# How do I add a layer in a shape of a box to an altair plot?

Tags: python-3.x, altair

I am trying to add a box to be used as strikezone using a pandas dataframe with coordinates and pass it to altair.

```
box = pd.DataFrame()
box.loc[:,"x"] = [-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5]
box.loc[:,'y'] = [1.25, 1.25, 0.5, 0.5]
```

I have tried the following:

```
g = alt.Chart(box.loc[0:1,:]).mark_line().encode(
x = 'x',
y = 'y')

d = alt.Chart(box.loc[1:2,:]).mark_line().encode(
x = 'x',
y = 'y')

e = alt.Chart(box.loc[2:3,:]).mark_line().encode(
x = 'x',
y = 'y')

f = alt.Chart(box.loc[3:4,:]).mark_line().encode(
x = 'x',
y = 'y')

g + d + e + f
```

I would also like to know how to adjust the x and y axis so there is a bit of a margin around the box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend drawing all four sides with a single line chart. You can then use the `domain` scale parameter to adjust the axis limits (see more in the [Adjusting Axis Limits](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#adjusting-axis-limits) section of Altair's documentation).

Here is an example:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

box = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5],
    'y': [1.25, 1.25, 0.5, 0.5, 1.25]
}).reset_index()


alt.Chart(box).mark_line().encode(
    alt.X('x', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(-1, 1))),
    alt.Y('y', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 1.5))),
    order='index'
)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use a `rect` mark to avoid having to construct the rectangle's coordinates manually in the right order:

```
box = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [-0.5], 'x2': [0.5], 'y1': [0.5], 'y2': [1.25]})

alt.Chart(box).mark_rect(fill='none', stroke='black').encode(
    alt.X('x1', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(-1, 1))),
    alt.Y('y1', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 1.5))),
    x2='x2',
    y2='y2'
)
```

[image]